# Как вставить символ табуляции в строку?

Tags: php

Так добавляет в текст символ вопроса в черном вертикальном ромбике :

```
$s = 'Просто текст';
$str[4] = "\t";
```

Кодировка Utf-8

Comment: вы как элемент масива вставляете надо просто `$str . "\t"`

Comment: $s = 'Просто текст'; $s .= "\t"; echo $s; "Просто текст "

Comment: @Naumov, вопрос не про вставку в конец, а про вставку в определенной позиции, неужели не ясно что `$str[4]` не является концом строки в данном случае.

Comment: вопрос не про вставку в конец, а про вставку в определенной позиции, неужели не ясно что `$str[4]` не является концом строки в данном случае

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего так себе, но просто как вариант: https://ideone.com/yagsbJ

```
<?php

$s = 'Просто текст';
$s = preg_replace('/^(.{3})./u', "$1\t", $s);
echo $s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно пишут в других ответах, ваша проблема в том, обращение к строке по индексу адресует байты, а русские буквы занимают в кодировке utf-8 по два байта. Отсюда и ромбик, означающий некорректный символ UTF-8.

Задачу можно решить [как строковыми функциями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842264/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83#842269), поддерживающими многобайтовые кодировки, так и регулярным выражением (не забыв добавить к шаблону модификатор `u`).

Если вам надо *вставить* знак табуляции после пятого символа (то есть добавить его между существующими символами), то подойдёт такое регулярное выражение

```
$s = 'Просто текст';
$s = preg_replace('/^(.{5})/u', "$1\t", $s);
echo $s;
```

Здесь мы берем первые 5 символов в захватывающую группу, и заменяем их на те же символы плюс добавляемая строка.

А если надо *заменить* пятый символ в строке на знак табуляции (как должен по идее работать ваш пример), то такое

```
$s = 'Просто текст';
$s = preg_replace('/^(.{4})./u', "$1\t", $s);
echo $s;
```

Здесь в регулярном выражении после захватывающей группы добавляется еще один (пятый) символ, который и будет в итоге заменен на новое значение

Answer (score -1):

С мультибайтными кодировками нельзя работать по прямым индексам - Вы адресуете не символы, а байты.

```
function replaceStrAt($str, $substr, $from, $to = null){
  is_null($to) and $to = $from;
  return mb_substr($str, 0, $from) . $substr . mb_substr($str, $to + 1);
}
function insertSubstrInto($str, $substr, $index){
  return mb_substr($str, 0, $index) . $substr . mb_substr($str, $index);
}

$s = 'И просто текст';

echo replaceStrAt($s, "\t", 4), "\n";     // И пр   сто текст
echo insertSubstrInto($s, "\t", 4), "\n"; // И пр   осто текст
```

[Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/gWdIF)

Comment: Смысл писать велосипед, когда уже существует `substr_replace`.

Comment: @And, a как может помочь substr_replace в unicode строке? Мой код просто работает, а вот как применять Ваш в реальной ситуации - неизвестно.

Comment: Но вам и это не поможет, если не будет установлена внутренняя кодировка. Если в строке не будет однобайтовых символов по типу цифр или англ. букв, функция отработает верно, а вот если добавить - это уже смесь. Хотя лучше конечно `mb_*`  юзать. тут не поспоришь.

Comment: кхм, чего минусите то, или есть другие варианты у кого то?

Comment: @And извините, но вы несете чушь. "однобайтовые символы по типу цифр или англ. букв," **ни малейшей проблемы** не составляют.

Answer (score -1):

Делается это так. Вначале с помощью mb_str_split() преобразуете строку в массив. Делаете его копию. После этого с каждым массивом делаете срез по нужной позиции с помощью array_slice() (один до, другой после). В конце объединяете массивы, а между ними свой нужный фрагмент текста. В конце результат преобразовываете в строку с помощью implode().

Проблема, как раньше заметили из-за юникода, поэтому приходится идти на ухищрения.

Comment: Что-то на вид тут дофига лишних действий...